# Возможно ли на react, js реализовать открытие файла в какой-либо программе сразу после скачивания?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, файлы, download

Возможно ли реализовать открытие файла сразу после скачивания на нативном js, возможно, из загрузок браузера? Браузер не может обработать exel, csv и подобные форматы, как, например, обрабатывает pdf.

Comment: у js нет доступа к такому